# HHVM not working with nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, hhvm

I try use HHVM with nginx in server CentOS 6.5 64bits but it's not working

```
hhvm --mode server -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000 -user nginx
```

Quote from HHVM's log:

> Failed to initialize central HHBC repository: Failed to open /var/log/hhvm/.hhvm.hhbc: 14 - unable to open database file
>
> Failed to open /var/www/.hhvm.hhbc: 14 - unable to open database file

Does someone know what to do in this situation ?

Comment: Partition was full in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here :

1. You're mentionning `/var/log/hhvm/.hhvm.hhbc` and `/var/www/hhvm/.hhvm.hhbc` .. is this a typo ? Can you give us the content of your `server.hdf` and `config.hdf` files ?
2. The folder `/var/log/hhvm` must be writeable by the account being used to run the webserver (ie `nginx`)

*(On a side note, I guess it's `--user`and not `-user`)*